# Background image doesn't work after assets precompile in RAILS4 production environment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I have following mixin in my **application.css.scss** file :

```
@mixin inputwithicon($iconname) {
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 20px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  text-indent: 0.30em;
  font-size:15px;
  font-weight:100;
  background: #FFFFFF url(assets/input/#{$iconname}.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 2% center;
}
```

This mixin works well on development but after precompiling assets and running in production it stops working (background isn't set).

I tried using `image-url` instead of `url`, but it didn't work.

Comment: What is different from development and production for you if anything? Also is background just not set at all or is it simply being overridden by another style?

Comment: Background isn't set at all. I'm having trouble with the url part. Inspect element doesn't show the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
background: #FFFFFF asset-url("assets/input/#{$iconname}.png") no-repeat;
```

--

In SASS, you would use `asset-url`; SCSS `asset_url`.

Either way, you need to use the above helper so that you when your assets are [*fingerprinted*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) through [precompilation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), the correct file being referenced by the pre-processor.

The problem you have is that `url` just calls a static filename. Whilst not a problem on its own, when you deploy your app, and precompilation occurs, you need to make sure the CSS is referencing the correct filename, hence the helper.

Comment: Precompile Error : 

Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...ut/#{$iconname}": expected ")", was ".png) no-repeat;"

How to get around this ?

Comment: Forgot to add quotes - the interpolation should work now

Comment: When you answer questions like this with crap titles, please do everyone a favor and *fix them*.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you to try one of this case.

1) Put your example.png inside app/assets/images/ and then use:

```
background-image:image-url("example.png");
```

2) Put your example.png inside app/public/img/ and then use:

```
background-image:url("/img/example.png");
```

Then indicate other css styles in this way:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
```

Hope it helps!